# 403 Error Logging into Github via Python Using urllib.request

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I'm getting the following error trying to log into Github via urllib.request using Python 3.4.2:

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

My assumption is I'm not mirroring a real user (tried doing so by adding a user-agent). I could use Selenium with PhantomJS but it's a bit too clunky and slow.

Yes, I could use Github's API, but the point is to learn how to log into a site using urllib, and I just wanted to try Github.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse


    #Login Info

    user_name = 'USERNAME'
    password = 'PASSWORD'

    #Request the login page to pull the auth token

    soup = urllib.request.urlopen('https://github.com/login')
    soup_content = soup.read()
    pretty_soup = BeautifulSoup(soup_content)

    #Request the auth token

    for tags in pretty_soup.findAll("meta", {'name': 'csrf-token'}):
        auth_token = tags['content']

    #Post login and auth token

    url = 'https://github.com/session'
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36'
    values = {'utf8' : '%E2%9C%93',
              'authenticity_token' : auth_token,
              'login' : user_name,
              'password' : password }

    headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    binary_data = data.encode('UTF-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, binary_data, headers)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
    pretty_page = BeautifulSoup(the_page)

    print(pretty_page)
```

EDIT 1:

Added how I would do this with Requests and not urllib based on a request in the comments. Issue now is the expected output would be to navigate to the account settings page on Github, however, I'm getting 302 redirected to a 403 error again.

I added HTTPBasicAuth because I though I might be having authentication issues. After trying that, I thought maybe to get the account settings page needed a cookie in the get() request, but still not working.

Here is the new code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

   #Pull login url content

   user_agent = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
   url = 'https://github.com/login'

   r = requests.get(url,headers=user_agent)

   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

   #Request the auth token

   for tags in soup.findAll("meta", {'name': 'csrf-token'}):
    auth_token = tags['content']

   #Post data   

   user_name = 'USERNAME'
   password = 'PASSWORD'

   session_url = u'https://github.com/session' #Url to post payload to

   payload = {'utf8' : '✓',
             'authenticity_token' : auth_token}

   auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user_name, password)

   with requests.Session() as s:

    #Post the payload and user agent to the session url    
       post_it = s.post(url=session_url, data=payload, auth=auth)
       cookie = post_it.headers['Set-Cookie']
       cookies = dict(cookies_are=cookie)

       # An authorised request.
       g = s.get('https://github.com/settings/profile',cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=True)
       new_soup = BeautifulSoup(g.content)

       #print(new_soup.title.text)

       ####### EXPECTED OUTPUT WOULD BE: 'Your Profile', e.g. the title tag for    https://github.com/settings/profile, NOT 'Sign In'

   #Test issues

   print('check login: \n',
                     user_agent,'\n',
                     url,'\n',
                     auth_token,'\n',
          'post login: \n',
                     session_url,'\n',
                     payload,'\n',
                     user_agent,'\n',
                     post_it,'\n',
                     g.history[0],'\n',
                     new_soup.title.text)
```

Comment: how about to try python `requests` library?

Comment: i'm not that familiar with `urllib`, but how do you specify POST request here?

Comment: Pretty sure it's in the req variable.